# Clipping a site display with an overlay div in a given viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am querying how it is possible to have a site, for arguments sake StackOverflow, where an overlay div can hide all of the content apart from what is inside the div. I suppose like a camera, you can only see whats in the viewfinder, not outside of it. I want for the moment for the viewfinder to be fixed.

I found: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KbXMC/)

which is close, but not quite. I have tried to google and ask friend devs but no luck in the resource department. Anyone got any ideas to get me started?

```
<html>
     <div class="content">
          <h1>All the page content divs</h1>
     </div>
     <div id="viewport-window"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe what you are refering to is called clipping with css: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: You have a couple of options, but this sounds more like browser plugin functionality than a website requirement. What is the overall aim?

Comment: Clipping! Thanks, I wasnt sure what it was called. Erm no, not browser plugin, its a portfolio site that wants this functionality but on mouse drag. I have built that bit, I just couldnt work out how to clip. thanks @xkcd149

Comment: I have added an image to get the gist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by applying a [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) style to the main element you want the overlay to be over (for instance `body` if you want the whole page). You could possibly also use [clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip) for more browser support, but do keep in mind it is being deprecated.

**Demo**

Has a static clip-path, but when moving mouse around it will change to a 200x200 viewport that follows the mouse

```js
jQuery(document).mousemove(function(e){
  var width = jQuery(document).width();
  var height = jQuery(document.body).height();
  
  var viewW = 200;
  var viewH = 200;
  
  var top = e.pageY - (viewH/2);
  var right = (width-e.pageX) - (viewW/2);
  var bottom = (height-e.pageY) - (viewH/2);
  var left = e.pageX - (viewW/2);
    
  var style = "inset("+top+"px "+right+"px "+bottom+"px "+left+"px)";
  
  jQuery(document.body).css({
     "-webkit-clip-path":style,
     "-moz-clip-path":style,
     "clip-path":style
  });
});
```

```css
body {
   -webkit-clip-path:inset(20px 200px 200px 40px);  
   -moz-clip-path:inset(20px 200px 200px 40px); 
   clip-path:inset(20px 200px 200px 40px);    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500" />
```

Comment: I have edited for more info. Thanks for helping but its not exactly what I need.

Comment: Hi. I was wondering, how would I go about doing this with divs? Basically, I have 2 main divs in my HTML. The first div holds the overlay which is a black background with some opacity. I am trying to select a section of a page via mousemove, like a drag select I suppose and I want to essentially clip that section of the page to show the elements behind it. So remove part of the overlay on the selected area to show the divs behind it and show it without the overlay.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do this without an "overlay" element.

Just use a giant box-shadow and a high z-index.

In this example I've used a `:hover` and the 'overlay` is slightly transparent.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: plum;
  position: relative;
}
.box:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="box">Lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div class="box">Lorem ipsum.</div>
</div>
```

Of course, this effect is purely *visual* the other elements are still accessible.

Comment: I think its close but not really in scope. I have updated the question

Comment: You have fundamentally changed the question. Please don't do that. I have rolled the question back to the original. If you have a **new** question, please ask it in a separate post.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that in 2 steps for example:

- First, create a div to overlay entire page and hide everything.
- Second, create a clone of your div(to be shown) with absolute position which has the same coordinates of the original location, and increase its z-index.

So, the logic is to hide everyting and show what you want over it. You could also visualize it with css or jquery animations.